# I lose hover effect on customize button background color

Tags: materialize

if I change the standard color of button background, I lose the hover effect.

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue"  href="">button</a>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href=""><i class="material-icons left">cloud</i>button</a>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href=""><i class="material-icons right">cloud</i>button</a>
```

Comment: It's working perfectly. In materiaize css button have a button has a hover effect of shadow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the background-color property are now *covered* by the new color you have selected. (In this case, I use blue darken-3).

[image]
[image]

Best solution is to create another hover pseudo-class for the button, and don't forget the suffix `!important`